# Getting the likes and comments of a photo from Facebook using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, facebook, css-selectors, screen-scraping

I'm looking forward to getting what the title describes. I've already found the way to log in and get the photos of any profile that I search for.
But when it comes to the comments or likes of any photo that I select, I cannot get them.
By this, I mean that Chromedriver clicks on the photo for displaying it, and I would like, while the photo is displayed, to get just the number of likes  (just the ones in blue) and the comments that are posted on that photo (right panel).
I'm not finding any tutorial or post that helps (indeed I've searched a lot).

Here's the way I'm looking for the photos, in case you need to see some of the code:

```
time.sleep(4)
imagenes = []
for i in ['photos_of','photos_all']:
    driver.get("https:/www.facebook.com/userBasedOnURL/" + i + "/")
    time.sleep(3)
    n_scrolls = 3
    for j in range(1, n_scrolls):
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(3)
        anchors = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        anchors = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in anchors]
        anchors = [a for a in anchors if str(a).startswith("https://www.facebook.com/photo")]
        #print(anchors)
        for a in anchors:
            driver.get(a)
            time.sleep(3)
            imagen = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("img")
            #print(imagen)
            imagenes.append(imagen[0].get_attribute("src"))
imagenes
```

Thanks in advance and pardon for my English.

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? Likes OR comments OR friend list? or all of the above? In a user profile or in post? Post on user's wall or post in group? All these are different situations and conditions...

Comment: Also, please ask for some specific, not to give you all the above I listed since each question here must be focused on 1 specific problem

Comment: Already changed to a more specific context. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, still not clear enough. Are you asking about number of likes or detailed number of all kinds of likes? Photo is on user's fall or after clicking on a photo so it is presented in photo viewer view?

Comment: Ok, I think now It's even more specific. Cheers mate!

Comment: You are aware that Facebook only allows you to use the API. And you risk getting banned.

Comment: No prob, I assume the risk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath to locate amount of likes under a photo in a photo viewer view is

```
//div[@aria-label="Photo Viewer"]//span[@class='pcp91wgn']
```

or in CSS selector syntax:

```
div[aria-label="Photo Viewer"] span[class="pcp91wgn"]
```

The comments there can be located with this CSS Selector

```
div[aria-label="Photo Viewer"] div[class="ecm0bbzt e5nlhep0 a8c37x1j"]
```

or with XPath syntax:

```
//div[@aria-label="Photo Viewer"]//div[@class="ecm0bbzt e5nlhep0 a8c37x1j"]
```

So you can iterate the list of links like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

photoview_comment_xpath = '//div[@aria-label="Photo Viewer"]//div[@class="ecm0bbzt e5nlhep0 a8c37x1j"]'
photoview_likes_amount_css = 'div[aria-label="Photo Viewer"] span[class="pcp91wgn"]'

likes = []
comments = []
for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    like = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, photoview_likes_amount_css))).text.strip()
    like.append(like)
    comments_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(photoview_comment_xpath)
    for comment in comments_elements:
        comments.append(comment.text.strip())
```

I don't think you will find tutorial about each specific web site. What you have to learn here is how to find stable unique locators for the web elements, and XPath and css selectors syntax

Comment: Be aware that the strings pcp91wgn, ecm0bbzt, e5nlhep0 and a8c37x1j may change any moment

Comment: I know. I verified that on several posts and saw it was same for all the occurrences.